# How to obtain full string of XmlElement

Tags: c#, xml, string, xml-parsing, xmldocument

I am trying to obtain the complete string of the query element (2nd element) within an xml string like the following:

```
"<iq type=\"result\" id=\"Roster\" to=\"JJJ@mail.kkk.com\"><query 
 xmlns=\"jabber:iq:roster\"><item jid=\"al@abc.def.com\" name=\"Albert\"
 subscription=\"both\"><group>A</group></item></query></iq>"
```

I am using XmlDocument and code that looks like this:

```
XmlDocument XDoc = new XmlDocument();
XDoc.LoadXml(DataBuf);
XmlElement QueryElem = XDoc.DocumentElement["query"];
string QueryBuf = QueryElem.InnerXml;
```

I need the full xml string starting with the query element.  The InnerXML method only returns the data starting with the "item" data.

How can I obtain the full string starting with query that ends with /query and that does not contain the iq element data?

Comment: Just out of curiosity. Why do you need this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`XmlNode.OuterXml`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.outerxml.aspx) property:

```
string QueryBuf = QueryElem.OuterXml;
```

returns

```
<query xmlns="jabber:iq:roster"><item jid="al@abc.def.com" name="Albert" subscription="both"><group>A</group></item></query>
```